# QueryString in WPF UserControl / View

Tags: .net, wpf, navigation, query-string, modern-ui

I'm trying to use the `<mui:ModernTab.Links>` collection in a UserControl to show a view containing a list of items. Ideally I'd like the tabs a category of data to show in the list. I was thinking of populating the list dynamically and passing the selected category using the query string perhaps, but I'm not sure how to get at the query string data from my view (which is a UserControl). Is there a better way of doing this? Maybe a style I could apply to a ListBox containing the items which would make it look like a modern UI tab list?

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about. the querystring is a `web` concept. WPF is a Windows Desktop application technology. It has nothing to do with web. You really really need to learn MVVM if you are working with WPF.

Comment: I guess I'm relating it to Windows Phone, where you do have a navigation context and can pass variables between pages using the query string. ModernUI navigates between user controls in a similar way.

Comment: still, IMO that is a horrible way to pass data between views. Use MVVM and use proper ViewModel.s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution using the ModernUI Framework is to use the context of the NavigationFrame, for which MUI provides helpers.

[This topic has more information](http://mui.codeplex.com/discussions/436518).